# Copy rows with a specific condition

Tags: excel, copy, excel-formula, autofilter

I have an assignment involving 32k rows of data. These data are grouped into five categories(let's say a,b,c,d,e) and these five categories repeat themselves starting from row 17. Therefore, it will look like this:

```
17  a
18  b
19  c
20  d
21  e
22  a
23  b
24  c
25  d
26  e
....
```

As you can see, categories repeat themselves starting from row 17 to the last row. What I need to do now is to copy data from each category. For instance, I need to copy all the data in category "a" or copy all the data in category "b" etc.

Comment: See [Filter data in a range or table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel's `Sort and Filter`:

1. Select the the headline cells of your data
2. Select from menu » Start » Sort and Filter » Filter
3. Open the category headline drop down menu (created from the filter) and select a category (or more).

also see this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soX8pYY5-08

Comment: ok, I did that. Now I have 5k rows of data. How do I copy them all?

Comment: Select them and Ctrl + C

Comment: Now, I have to do the same process with numbers. I have to select the numbers with a period of five times. For instance, I have the following set:     3; 4; 2; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 0; 1.2; 5.4; 1.5; 3.5; 2.3; 3; 5; 4; 3; 2. Here, I have to select the first number(3) and all the numbers that are five numbers after each other. Therefore, in the set above, the numbers will be 3; 7; 5.4; 5. How do I do that?